# Play Scala No Json deserializer found for type (String, String). Try to implement an implicit Reads or Format for this type

Tags: scala, playframework

These Json serializers in Play with Scala are driving me nuts.

I have read dozens of posts and the tutorials and the documentation. Tried four different ways of implementing Reads / Writes / Format overrides and all to no avail.

So I backed off the custom type and decided to go uber simple:

```
  def suggest = Action(parse.json) {
    request =>
      request.body.validate[(String, String)].map {
        case (suggestion, categories) => Ok("You suggested " + suggestion + " for categories " + categories)
      }.recoverTotal {
        e => BadRequest(JsError.toFlatJson(e))
      }
  }
```

And the error comes back as noted in the subject.

Do I *really* need to provide a custom Reads / Writes / Format implementation for such a basic body?

A sample input body could be:

```
{"suggestion":"add generics", "categories":"request;language;updates"}
```

What simple thing am I missing?

Answer (score 6):

Play! gives you a LOT of ways to work with Json. From the looks of your code, you're going down the Tuple road. Which essentially lets you convert Json into a Tuple. You're also using 'reads' which has the downside that you don't get *precise* error reporting (ie: if invalid json was passed you would know its invalid... but you wouldn't necessarily know *why* it was invalid). If you wanted more error handling then you need to start using the 'validate' method (details here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaJsonCombinators).

Another way you could go is to map Json to case classes doing something like:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

case class MyClass(
  suggestion: String,
  categories: String
)

object MyClass {
  implicit val readsMyClass: Reads[MyClass] = new Reads[MyClass] {
    def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[MyClass] = {
      for {
        suggestion <- (json \ "suggestion").validate[String]
        categories <- (json \ "categories").validate[String]
      } yield MyClass(json,categories)
    }
  }
}
```

This seems like a lot of code so Play 2.1 introduced Json 'Inception' which I have yet to try (http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaJsonInception).

Finally, if you want the Json validation but don't necessary need to marshall/unmarshall case classes, then you can try the 'coast-to-coast' method. This will keep all your json as JsObject types but still give you validation. Sample code here: https://github.com/mandubian/play2-json-demo/blob/master/json-coast-to-coast/app/controllers/Application.scala

Hope this helps.

Comment: The JsonInception thing works fine if you want the default behavior "serialize all fields".

Answer (score 2):

So I added this:

```
  implicit val rds = (
    (__ \ 'suggestion).read[String] and
    (__ \ 'categories).read[String]
  ) tupled
```

And that seems to work.

Curious, though, is this really the best way to do this? It seems like a LOT of code if you have many many types to serialize / deserialize.